# Fujitsu RX200 S7 "Main 5V" Error

Tags: hardware

One of our Fujitsu RX200 S7 servers hangs on boot with the global error orange light flashing.

The IRMC systemlog shows a "Main 5V" error (0.02V instead of 5V). Does this mean we have to change the mainboard, the power distribution board, or the power supply?

A simple reconnect of all cables did not help.

Answer (score 0):

The server failure reason is a faulty chip Volterra vt261bwf. It is under the SAS controller. This is a shiny surface chip about the size of 3mm x 3mm